# Asp.net MVC5 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to ask you some questions about asp.net mvc5. I'm writing right now a mid-advanced (for me for sure :D) application. What i want to get and what is my problem?

I created a basic MVC page with registration and login from asp.net template. Now i want to extend this page with my ideas.

First: I want to add new entities which will have a foreign keys from other tables (for example from AspNetUser). How can I push data into database when i need as foreign key User ID from table AspNetUser? - I think that in my model class i have to add public ApplicationUser user {get;set;} and ICollection myModels {get;set;} in ApplicationUser class, then in controller my Action must get all parameters (included foreign key), but what next? How can i get User id from table AspNetUser? Can you give me, please, a basic example of this idea?

Second: What is better? Code first or Database first?

Please, help me. This is very important for me, because without this i will not graduate..

Comment: First, work on formatting your question - it is barely readable right now. Second - what you are asking is a tutorial, there are plenty of those. If I understood you correctly and my own understanding of the domain is correct look for UserManager and SignInManager classes (or names alike) and read about Principals and Identities it should clarify how authentication works

Answer (score 0):

You have to look inside `EntityValidationErrors` to find out what exactly went wrong, if I had to guess I then think it has to do with this line in your `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public ICollection<TaskModel> TaskModels { get; set; }
```

First, you should mark this property with the `virtual` keyword to enabled lazy loading.

Then you need to configure this One-To-Many relationship in Entity Framework. You can do that by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your `OtherDbContext`, then configuring the relationship like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(e => e.TaskModel)
        .WithRequired(e => e.ApplicationUser)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

But, you don't really need this unless you plan on using the `TaskModels` collection, so you can just remove the collection completely and that should fix your problem.

BTW, I personally prefer to implement my foreign key relationships like this:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
public string UserId { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

This way my foreign key reference is not a magic string, and it's right next to the navigation property. I find it much cleaner and safer.

I haven't tested any of this code but hopefully I got it right :-)

Comment: So.. I created new project and did it all over again. It works even without OnModelCreating and virtual property. I dont know what was wrong, but I guess that was something with Database - I mean migrations etc.

Comment: You're right it's not necessary to do the OnModelCreating since the attribute defines the relationship already, though you will need it if you want to configure cascading. Glad it works though!

Answer (score 0):

So.. I created new project and did it all over again. It works even without OnModelCreating and virtual property. I dont know what was wrong, but I guess that was something with Database - I mean migrations etc.

for everyone who has the same problem:

Just add virtual properties to our new model class (before this you have to decide what relation you want to use ;)), then in IdentityModel.cs add another virtual properties to class ApplicationUser and remember to use correct DbContext :)

Thanks guys for help and have a nice day!!!

Comment: remember to set Id as int, not string. This may also cause an error